# Quarkus can't connect to Keycloak over SSL. Misconfiguration or Issue?

Tags: ssl, connection, keycloak, quarkus

i have a Problem with Quarkus and Keycloak. When Quarkus tries to verify a Token with Keycloak it gives me following Error: 
`2019-10-01 07:40:02,353 ERROR [org.key.ada.rot.JWKPublicKeyLocator] (executor-thread-1) Error when sending request to retrieve realm keys: org.keycloak.adapters.HttpClientAdapterException: IO error
...
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
...
2019-10-01 07:40:02,359 ERROR [org.key.ada.rot.AdapterTokenVerifier] (executor-thread-1) Didn't find publicKey for kid: <some-key>`

Quarkus Version: 0.22.0

Java Version:
  openjdk version "1.8.0_222"
  OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_222-8u222-b10-1ubuntu1~18.04.1-b10)
  OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.222-b10, mixed mode)

OS: "Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS"

Im using Keycloak with SSL. Without SSL the Error did not happen.
I am now not sure if this is an Issue on my side, and if it is on my side, what did i do wrong?

Comment: Is this in native mode or in JVM mode?

Comment: Its in JVM mode.

Comment: Are you sure your Keycloak instance is working correctly?

Comment: The Keycloak instance is in fact working corretly. It works with other services wo problem. I've gotten info, that its probably the certificates in my truststore. So im currently looking into that.

Comment: Did You find any solution?